# Unity how to scale gameobjects using mouseclick?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scaling, gameobject

does anyone know how to scale up different game objects using mouse click and after doing the scaling, the game object should not be able to scale up again. Currently my code is able to scale up but its not what i wanted.
Heres my current code:

```
public void ScaleForRuler()
{       
    transform.localScale += new Vector3 (3.0F, 0, 0.1F);

}       
void OnMouseDown()
{
    if (touch == false) 
    {
        if(ruler.GetComponent<Collider>().name == "Ruler")
        {
            ScaleForRuler ();
            touch = true;
            Debug.Log (touch);
        }
        if(TriangleThingy.GetComponent<Collider>().name == "Triangle_Set_Square_Ruler")
        {
            ScaleForTriangleThingy ();
            touch = true;
            Debug.Log (touch);
        }
         if (Tsquare.GetComponent<Collider> ().name == "Tsquare") 
        {               
            if (LineR.GetComponent<Collider> ().name == "LineRight" || LineL.GetComponent<Collider> ().name == "LineLeft") 
            {
                TsquareScaleForTB ();
                touch = true;
                Debug.Log (touch);
            } 
            else if (LineB.GetComponent<Collider> ().name == "LineBottom" || LineT.GetComponent<Collider> ().name == "LineTop") 
            {
                TsquareScaleForTB ();
                touch = true;
                Debug.Log (touch);
            }                   
        }
        if (protractor.GetComponent<Collider> ().name == "Protractor") 
        {
            ScaleForProtractor ();
            touch = true;
            Debug.Log (touch);
            Debug.Log ("protractor scale");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please explain why your code is not what you wanted?

Comment: What is the "ruler"? Also what do you mean by "its using the values for the other gameobject together with the values for the ruler"?

Comment: The scale up values, like for example when you drag the ruler up, the ruler does scale up but its using the values for the other gameobject together with the values for the ruler. Which this happen after putting in the gameobject for the public gameobjects, but after removing all except the one for certain gameobject, it gives a unassigned reference error. So i wanted to ask if i could just use a single script to control scaling for many diff objects. The values are the values thats suppose to be use by other game objects.

Comment: As you can see, i have put in the debug.log for 4 gameobjects but for some reason, the console is showing all 4 debug.log messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stop using `OnMouseDown()`, Unity has introduced since a while some new handler interfaces like `IPointerDownHandler`, `IDragHandler`, etc. within the `EventSystem` class, which works perfectly with mouse AND touch inputs.

It's not really clear what you want to achieve, if you want to scale every single object separately when it's clicked or just scale all together regardless which one is clicked.

I'll assume you want to be able to scale all objects separately. The steps to do that are the following:

1) Add the `Physics 2D Raycaster` component to your scene camera.

2) To every single object you want to scale, add this simple script:

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class ScaleExample : MonoBehaviour, IBeginDragHandler, IDragHandler, IEndDragHandler {

    private Vector2 startPosition;
    private float scalingFactor = .01f;
    private bool isObjectAlreadyScaled = false;

    public void OnBeginDrag(PointerEventData eventData) {
        startPosition = Vector2.zero;
    }

    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData) {
        if (!isObjectAlreadyScaled) {
            startPosition += eventData.delta;
            var scalingAmount = new Vector2(Mathf.Abs(startPosition.x), Mathf.Abs(startPosition.y));
            transform.localScale = (Vector3)scalingAmount * scalingFactor;
        }
    }

    public void OnEndDrag(PointerEventData eventData) {
        isObjectAlreadyScaled = true;
    }
}
```

The example works with 2D objects (i.e.: scales up the X and Y of the object), you can ofc change this very easily in order to accomodate different coordinates scaling.
The use of the interfaces should be clear by example: `OnBeginDrag` is called once as soon as the dragging starts, `OnDrag` is called repeatedly every time there's a change in the position of the pointer during the drag, and `OnEndDrag` is called as soon as the drag is over (i.e.: user releases the button/finger).

Comment: Oh really thks for the help but i manage to found a way around using the current script. As currently im using the touchscript from the assets store, i planning to use the on transform complete on their transform gesture script.

Answer (score 1):

In a comment to your question, you wrote

> So i wanted to ask if i could just use a single script to control scaling for many diff objects

**The answer is yes** (and it is a really good idea also)

Here is an idea on how to do it:

From the doc of [OnMouseDown](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown.html):

> OnMouseDown is called when the user has pressed the mouse button while over the GUIElement or Collider.

This means that if your script contains the OnMouseDown function:

```
private void OnMouseDown()
{

}
```

you can add this script to several different objects. If you click on object1, the function will be called only for object1. If you click on object2, the function will be called for object2. So you don't need to check which object is clicked.

Your script should look like this:

```
private void OnMouseDown()
{
    // touch is a boolean, you don't need to write touch == true, it will do it automatically
    // Also, instead of nesting all the code if touch == false, we just stop if it is true, so the code is easier to read
    if (touch)
        return; 

    touch = true;
    Debug.Log (touch);

    // transform is the transform of the object that has the script
    // you don't need any check
    transform.localScale += new Vector3 (3.0f, 0f, 0.1f);  
}
```

I hope this helps

Good luck